# How does energy momentum tensor generate transformations?

Tags: stress-energy-momentum-tensor, classical-field-theory, poisson-brackets

I am reading https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0008096 on p.20.

Since I am not very familiar with the general canonical formalism, I have some trouble interpreting the following statements:

Consider the energy momentum tensor of a (classical) field theory
$$
T^{\mu \nu} = \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu} \phi) } \partial^{\nu} \phi - g^{\mu \nu} \mathcal L
$$
Let
$$
A[f] = \int_{\Sigma} d\sigma_{\mu} f_{\nu}(x) T^{\mu \nu}(x),
$$
where $\Sigma$ is a space-like hypersurface.
Now it is stated that $A$ generates infinitesimal transformations like
$$
\delta_f B(x) = f_{\mu}(x) \partial^{\mu} B(x)
\\
\delta_f x^{\mu} = f^{\mu}(x)
$$
I am guessing that $\delta_f B = \{ A[f] , B \}$, where $\{...\}$ is the Poisson bracket. But then I am not sure how it works. If we say that $x^{\mu},p^{\mu}$ are the canonical variables we have
$$
\{ A[f] , B \} = (\partial^{\mu} B) \frac{\partial A[f]}{\partial p^{\mu}}
$$
and we should have $\frac{\partial A[f]}{\partial p^{\mu}} = f_{\mu}$?

Also I am confused, since I thought that in field theory the canonical pairs are $\phi$ and probably something like $\pi = N^{\mu} \frac{\partial \mathcal L}{\partial (\partial_{\mu} \phi) } $, where $N^{\mu}$ is the normal on $\Sigma$.

Comment: It is something silly. Energy and momentum are the generator of time evolution and space translations. You were just writing down the energy momentum tensor. Ergo, it would generate transformations.

Comment: Right. But I am asking how exactly does it work in this case, i.e. what exactly is $\delta_f$ and how do I see how it acts on some function. The suggestions I made in the posts are just guesses and the derivation is incomplete.